# python regular expression splitting some strings only in certain orders

Tags: python, regex, parsing, tokenize

I have the following tokenizeAndParse(s) function that takes a string and attempts to tokenize it to an array of strings

```
def tokenizeAndParse(s):
    tokens = re.split(r"(\s+|assign|:=|print|\+|if|while|{|}|;|[|]|,|@|for|true|false|call|procedure|not|and|or|\(|\))", s)
    tokens = [t for t in tokens if not t.isspace() and not t == ""]
    print("hello",tokens)
```

Some examples of the the function

```
tokenizeAndParse("assign abc := [true, true, true];")
hello ['assign', 'abc', ':=', '[', 'true', ',', 'true', ',', 'true', ']', ';']

tokenizeAndParse("print 5+5;")
hello ['print', '5', '+', '5', ';']
```

I am running into an interesting problem, if I call the following, the **4** and the **]** aren't parsed as separate tokens and I have no idea why. As demonstrated above, if it is **true** before the **]** the function works fine.

```
 tokenizeAndParse("assign abc := [true, true, 4];")
 hello ['assign', 'abc', ':=', '[', 'true', ',', 'true', ',', '4]', ';']
```

further playing with the function demonstrates that if its a number before the **]**, it will not parse correctly. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are not splitting on numbers. Replace below code line:

```
tokens = re.split(r"(\s+|assign|:=|print|\+|if|while|{|}|;|[|]|,|@|for|true|false|call|procedure|not|and|or|\(|\))", s)
```

as shown in the below lines:

```
>>> def tokenizeAndParse(s):
    tokens = re.split(r"(\s+|assign|:=|print|\+|if|while|{|}|;|[|]|,|@|for|true|false|call|procedure|not|and|or|\(|\)|[0-9]+)", s)
    tokens = [t for t in tokens if not t.isspace() and not t == ""]
    print("hello",tokens)

>>> tokenizeAndParse("assign abc := [true, true, 4];")
('hello', ['assign', 'abc', ':=', '[', 'true', ',', 'true', ',', '4', ']', ';'])
```

This will fix the issue.